# How can I use jq to get latitude and longitude without losing trailing zeros?

Tags: linux, bash, precision, jq

I am trying to use the `jq` command inside a `bash` script as

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout -t 15 gpspipe -w -n 8 gpsd | jq '{latitude:.lat,longitude:.lon}' |
{
  # do something
}
```

So my input from `gpspipe`

```
{
    "lat":34.284606710,
    "lon":-12.543774500
}
```

If I use jq to get lat and lon values the result would be: `"34.28460671"` for latitude and `"-12.5437745"` for longitude.

What I would like is to get the values as strings (with the trailing zeros) i.e. `"34.284606710"` and `"12.543774500"`

So basically, my problem is that I can't get lat and lon as strings (with the trailing zeros), using `jq` in a `bash` script.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: I need those coordinates for setting the location of a device as his current location. Without the trailing zeros the location would be wrong.

Comment: Sorry i quite did not get you.. a simple `object.lat.toString()` will do to get the values as string, doesn't it?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze sorry for the confusion created. I am dealing with a bash script, not javascript. I updated my question

Comment: oh alrighty:D good luck!

Comment: what's your input, a file OR a string?

Comment: Show your current script

Comment: @am1991: Is it always 9 trailing digits after `.`?

Comment: @Inian yes. always 9 digits.

Comment: So your device would require you to use `34.000000000` instead of just `34`? Yikes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using a `pad` function:

```
def pad(n):"\(.)"|(split(".")+["0"])[:2]|.[1]|=(.+"0"*n)[:n]| join(".");
"\(.lat|pad(9)) \(.lon|pad(9))"
```

Explaination

```
def pad(n):
     "\(.)"                  # convert to string
   | (split(".")+["0"])[:2]  # split into whole and fractional parts
   | .[1]|=(.+"0"*n)[:n]     # keep first n digits after adding n zeros to fraction
   | join(".")               # combine back into a string
   ;
```

You can see how it works at https://jqplay.org/s/e8ZHP1t_K3

With your sample data in `data.json` and the above filter in `filter.jq` the command

```
$ jq -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
34.284606710 -12.543774500
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use jq to get latitude and longitude without loosing
>   trailing zeros?
>   Blockquote

Change your JSON response value to String

```
{"lat":34.284606710,"lon":-12.543774500}
```

to

`{"lat":"34.284606710","lon":"-12.543774500"}`

Parse with

> String latitude =object.lat.toString();
>
> String longitude=object.lon.toString();

In this way you'll never ever loosing anything from your JSON response.

Comment: No matter what you using, If you well know about JSON & define String/Text as a value, It helps you solve your problem i.e "21.1210000" or '34.34343403040'

Answer (score 1):

In a `bash` script you could use `jq` with string interpolation to get the latitude and longitude values and do zero padding with `printf()`. The `-r` flag in `jq` will strip the double-quotes from the values and feed them to the while-loop.

```
timeout -t 15 gpspipe -w -n 8 gpsd | jq -r '"\(.lat) \(.lon)"' | while read -r lat lon; do 
    printf -v z_lat "%.9f" "$lat"
    printf -v z_lon "%.9f" "$lon"
    printf "Padded lat: %s Padded lon: %s\n" "${z_lat}"  "${z_lon}"    
done
```

The `printf -v` does the required formatting from the variable received from `jq` and applying the trailing zero padding needed and store in variables `z_lat` and `z_lon`.